# Unable to restart distributed cache service : cacheHostInfo is null

Tags: distributedcache

I've tried several steps from other questions. After removing the service instance and running the command `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstace` I receive the error:

> Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance :
>   ErrorCode:SubStatus:No such host is
>   known

The AppFabric Caching Service is running and the service will show up under services after running the command, but cannot be started.

Running the command `Get-CacheHost` gives:

> HostName: ServerName
>
> CachePort: 22233
>
> ServiceName: AppFabricCachingService
>
> Service Status: UNKNOWN
>
> Version Info: 0 [0,0][0,0]

This is a staging environment with one sharepoint server and one sql server

Comment: Have you seen this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sambetts/archive/2014/03/19/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-appfabric-troubleshooting.aspx ?

Comment: Yes, when I run those commands the server is correct for the serviceinstance, but the hostname for `Get-CacheHost` is incorrect. When I use the `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` the incorrect server name is what gets set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another server was originally setup as the cache host for the farm. It had since been removed, but the cache host was never reconfigured. I unregistered the cache host and registered it using the correct server credentials.

Once this change was made, running the `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance` cmdlet resolved my issue. Thank you [Amal Hashim](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/34350/amal-hashim) for pointing me in the right direction.